# EF Core Data Migration Moved to Separate Project; how to get connection string?

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations, dbcontext

I have refactored my project and have created a new project for the purposes of migrations (we'll call it MyProject.Data.  I have another project in the solution named MyProject.App.

I have everything working however I have the connection string hard-coded in MyProject.Data.  I would like to use the appsettings.json fie in the MyProject.Data.  Is there a way for the MyProject.Data to reference the appSettings.json file in the MyProject.Data without having to hard code the path of the .json file?

Thanks

--- Val

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the correct way to do this or not, however it does work for me.  If there is a better way to do this then I'm all ears!

```
string _connectionString;

public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options) : base(options)
   {
      string appSettings = String.Concat(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "/appsettings.json");
      var configurationSettings = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile(appSettings).Build();
      _connectionString = configurationSettings["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"];
    }
```